# Почему не передается сигнал во вторую форму?

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты

Пишу программу на С++ в Qt, суть программы в том, что есть одно окно с тремя кнопками, каждая кнопка открывает новое окно и должна передать ему свой номер, типо если первая кнопка то номер один и тд. Но у меня не получается это сделать, сигнал из одного окна просто не проходит во второе, я решил разобраться на простом примере что когда нажимаем на кнопку то просто происходит сигнал и второе окно должно его поймать и вывести "OPENED!!" вот как я это сделал:

MainWindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mathwindow.h"
    
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
    namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE
    
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
     ~MainWindow();
    
private slots:
    void openNewWindow();
signals:
    void buttonN();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

mathwindow *math;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(openNewWindow()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
    
void MainWindow::openNewWindow() {
    math = new mathwindow();
    math->show();
    emit buttonN();
}
```

mathwindow.h:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include "mainwindow.h"
    
namespace Ui {
    class mathwindow;
}
    
class mathwindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    explicit mathwindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~mathwindow();
 public slots:
    void grabValue();
 private:
    Ui::mathwindow *ui;
 };
```

mathwindow.cpp

```
#include "mathwindow.h"

#include "ui_mathwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
mathwindow::mathwindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::mathwindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow var;
    connect(&var,SIGNAL(buttonN()),this,SLOT(grabValue()));
}

mathwindow::~mathwindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void mathwindow::grabValue() {
    qDebug()<<"OPENED!!";
}
```

И слово `OPENED!!` никак почему то не выводиться, я подозреваю что это потому что я в одной функции открываю второе окно и сразу вырабатывается сигнал, помогите как это реализовать?

Чтобы когда открывалось второе окно ему сразу передавался нужный сигнал.

Comment: Второе окно просто не подписывается на сигнал родительского окна. Вместо этого зачем-то создается еще одно окно `MainWindow var;`, сразу же выходящее из области видимости.

Comment: @user7860670 а что мне сделать?)

Comment: не создавать `MainWindow var;`, а подписываться на сигналы родительского окна

Comment: @user7860670 а как мне это сделать? просто в connect написать (MainWindow...)? или как мне его туда передать?

Comment: @user7860670 connect(MainWindow,SIGNAL(buttonN()),this,SLOT(grabValue())); вот так пишет ошибку(( а как надо? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: ссылку на экземпляр `MainWindow` необходимо передавать к констуктор дочернего окна, короче в то место, где происходит подписка

Comment: @user7860670 connect(&MainWindow,SIGNAL(buttonN()),this,SLOT(grabValue())); ?? вот так чтоли? Я правда не очень понимаю((

Comment: начните с "ссылку на экземпляр MainWindow необходимо передавать к констуктор дочернего окна"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так - здесь `mathwindow` это поле класса главного окна (объект _mathWindow см. внизу класса MainWindow):

```
#include "mathwindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) 
    : QMainWindow(parent) {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(openNewWindow()));
    }

    ~MainWindow() {
    }

private slots:
    void openNewWindow() {
        // Если окно еще не было создано, то создать
        if( _mathWindow.isNull() ) { 
            // this - указатель на главное окно приложения
            _mathWindow.reset(new mathwindow(this));
        }
        // Показать
        _mathWindow->show();
       
        // Грабануть
        _mathWindow->grabValue();
    }
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    // Использование QScopedPointer обезопасит от утечек памяти
    QScopedPointer<mathwindow> _mathWindow;
};
```

mathwindow.h:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include "mainwindow.h"
    
namespace Ui {
    class mathwindow;
}
    
class mathwindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    explicit mathwindow(MainWindow* mainWindow, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~mathwindow();
 public slots:
    void grabValue();
 private:
    Ui::mathwindow *ui;
    MainWindow* _mainWindow;
 };
```

mathwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mathwindow.h"

#include "ui_mathwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

mathwindow::mathwindow(MainWindow* mainWindow, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::mathwindow),
    _mainWindow(mainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    
}

mathwindow::~mathwindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void mathwindow::grabValue() {
    qDebug() << "OPENED!!";
}
```

Comment: А если мне надо как у меня? с двумя файлами? как мне передать главный файл в connect что бы переменную var не создавать?

Comment: @leocoolguy0 сделал так, чтобы ничего лишнего не создавать. Добавил код окна `mathwindow`

Comment: А что изменилось?? где connect?

Comment: Я имел ввиду что мне такой способ реализации не очень подходит, я имел ввиду можете через connect так же как у меня просто передать в него ссылку на родителя а то я не очень понимаю как

Comment: @leocoolguy0 это тоже самое, что и у вас, только без ошибок. Скопируйте себе код и запустите - все работает.

Comment: А можно сделать именно как у меня? просто мне правда как у меня удобнее, я просто не понимаю одну вещь как мне в connect передавать ссылку на само окно mainwindow с которым я щас работаю

Comment: @leocoolguy0 параметром конструктора mathwindow

Comment: Не понимаю как это сделать(( можете это в ответ добавить((((

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109267/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-leocoolguy-0).